# Graphical meaning of the limit that defines derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, graphing-functions

We know that a function $f(x)$ is continuous at a point $c$ if

$$\lim\limits_{x\to{c}}f(x)=f(c)$$
I am able to visualise it geometrically. What this means is that both the right hand and left hand limits at the point c are equal and are $f(c)$. In plain terms, that means if we go from the left hand side or the right hand side of the point c, the value of $f(x)$ is same and is equal to $f(c)$

A derivative is defined if the following limit exists:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to{0}}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
But what is the geometric interpretation of this limit not existing?

If this limit doesn't exist, then

$$\lim\limits_{h\to{0^+}}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}≠\lim\limits_{h\to{0^-}}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

But I am not able to visualise what this geometrically means?

It would help me immensely if I would be able to visualise it on a graph.

Question:

How to visualise it geometrically (or graphically) if this limit does not exists?$$\lim\limits_{h\to{0}}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: An easy graph to visualize this on would be $f(x)=|x|$. Specifically, try calculating $f'(0)$. What happens when you approach $x=0$ from the left side? What about the right side?

Comment: For example, you might picture the ramp function $r(x) = \max(x,0)$. Draw its graph, then compute the "derivative from the right" and the "derivative from the left" at $0$.

Comment: I totally agree with the above two comments. Analyze them. But here is an even simpler meaning: The geometrical significance of the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is the same as the geometrical meaning of $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}g(h)$, where $g(h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Comment: You probably should be looking at $\lim\limits_{h\to{0}}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$ instead of $\lim\limits_{h\to{0}}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ to better connect this part with your first paragraph. Also, *If this limit doesn't exist, then* --- This seems to assume that each of the one-sided limits exists. There are other ways for the derivative to exist than this, because the one-sided limits might not exist. For the derivative to not exist, all you need is one sequence of numbers approaching $c$ such that the limit of the difference quotient of those numbers (computed relative to $c)$ to not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is the limit of the slope of the secant, if the right hand and left hand derivative exist but are not equal then that means the limit of slope of the secant from end does not equal the limit of the slope of the secant from the other end.